# Giving $Top(X,Y)$ an appropriate topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $Top$ be the category of topological spaces. Let $X,Y$ be objects in $Top$.

Let $F:\mathbb{I}\rightarrow Top(X,Y)$ be a function (I will denote the image of $t$ by $F_t$). Let $F_{*}:X\times \mathbb{I}\rightarrow Y$ be the function that sends $(x,t)$ to $F_t(x)$.

Is there a topology on $Top(X,Y)$ such that $F$ is continuous iff $F_{*}$ is continuous ?

Comment: If $X$ is locally compact (need not be Hausdorff), then you get the "only if" statement. The "if" direction is always true. Here $Y^X$ is equipped with the compact-open topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category#Examples), the category $\mathbf{Top}$ is not cartesian closed which makes the property you're looking for extremely difficult to exist. If there were further conditions on $X$ and $Y$ then it might be possible (for instance the category of compactly generated Hausdorff spaces is cartesian closed). Usually, a function space in topology is given the [compact-open topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) although there are other 'natural' topologies that you can put on a function space. Most notably, the product topology given by the space of set-theoretic functions.